# How to assign a hexadecimal value to integer type in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, typecast

ModelSim is unable to compile this in VHDL:

```
constant mem_size_bytes: integer := x"FFFFFFFF";
```

It says:

```
Bit string literal found where non-array type std.STANDARD.INTEGER was expected.
```

Similarly for;

```
if address< x"3FFFFF" then
```

it says

```
Operator "<" is ambiguous
```

I keep running into this problem. How in the world am I supposed to use hexadecimal numbers in VHDL with integer types like integer, natural and positive? Its just that specifying something hexadecimal is more convinient at times than having to use the calculator to determine what something is in radix-10. I had hoped that the tool will automatically know what the literal means since it is preceded by x which marks it as hexadecimal numeric quantity!!!

So, when assigning literals to constants or when using literals in comparison operator how does one qualify the literal? In other word for a literal constant value like "1010", how do explicitly tell the compiler if this is a string or std_logic_vector or unsigned or signed?

Comment: See [based_literal](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00041.htm), where the the negative one expression (for the minimum supported integer size) would be `16#FFFFFFFF#`. Integers are scalar while bit strings and string literals are associated with arrays of character types (and std_ulogic is a character enumerated type). Simply put, integers don't got bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VHDL supports arithmetic values but it has to know if they are signed or unsigned. I recommend using the numeric_std library to support these types.

VHDL is strongly typed. For your first question, I would use:

EDIT: I have erased a prior more complex form and used this simpler one after Brian Dummond's comment

```
constant mem_size   : integer := x"FFFF_FFFF";
```

The second, supposing address is an std_logic_vector, has to be written:

```
if unsigned(address) < x"3FFFFF" then
```

Comment: Downvoted for recommending unnecessary type conversions. Prefer the simpler solution of using the right syntax `16#3fffff#` for based integer literals.

Comment: I did not know about this # format. None of the resources I have show these. I will try it out.

Comment: Ok, how does one qualify the literals that are string of bits like "1010" as std logic vector, unsigned, signed or something else?

Comment: For vectors of bits or of std_logic, either "1010" or x"A"  work. For base 2 integer literals, 2#1010#.   And of course, 6 * 9 = 13#42#.

Comment: @quantum231 then none of your resources are a decent textbook. I still turn to Ashenden "Designer's Guide to VHDL" most often.

Comment: Brian, I was able to get the textbook you recommended, I only wish I knew of this book earlier but anyway, thanks guru